# Why my vote to close (duplicate) on my own question is nto authoritative?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I asked a question and discovered after some time that it is a duplicate. I flagged it (my question) as such but my vote was recorded as a vote only.

Why isn't it authoritative to close the question as duplicate?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been simpler just to delete your question?

Comment: I considered that but since I did not find the linked question /answer during my first search I think it is worthwhile to keep another wording of the question which can help pepole in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has [been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261430/154443) a few times on Meta.SE as it applies to all of Stack Exchange.

That one has been a feature request since July 2015, and various folks agree it would be useful, but there is no action on it yet. From looking at those type of questions it looks like it's not high enough priority to get it done "now", as the existing functionality does work as normal.